# Best Control For Step By Step Data Gathering

Tags: c#, .net

i am writing some kind of survey program in c#. I have 29 different questions and user should start from 1st quetion to 29. Which control is proper for this program ? Like wizard control.

Comment: Is buying one an option for you? Windows Forms or WPF or Silverlight...?

Comment: That really depends on how you want the survey to look, and whether or not answers to early questions affect the wording/options available in later questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this  [Wizard control](http://winformswizard.codeplex.com/) in Codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links found with this Google search:
http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+Wizard+Component&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-au:IE-Address&ie=&oe=

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/DesignTimeWizard.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/windowsaerostylewizard.aspx

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10010548/how-to-make-a-wizard-application.aspx

There's heaps of info on this and the controls you can find online are pretty good. But I've always found that if you want complete control it's easier to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

why not use online free ones?  i would better consider doing it as Web/Online to make it easily distributable to wider audience, also gathering feedback will be easier as well.